# L'Hospital rule for product

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I consider the function $$ h_t:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},x\mapsto t\cdot x\cdot (1-t)^x $$ with $ t\in [0,1] $. I want to confirm  $ \lim h_t(x)=0 $ by L'Hospital rule like this: It is with $ t\in]0,1[ $
$$ \begin{align}\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}h_t(x)&=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}t\cdot x\cdot (1-t)^x=t\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}x\cdot (1-t)^x=t\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{\frac{1}{(1-t)^x}}\\&=t\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{(1-t)^{-x}}=t\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{e^{-x\cdot \ln(1-t)}}\stackrel{L'H}{=}t\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{e^{-x\cdot \ln(1-t)}\cdot (-\ln(1-t))}\\&=-\frac{t}{\ln(1-t)}\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{e^{-x\cdot \ln(1-t)}}\stackrel{L'H}{=}-\frac{t}{\ln(1-t)}\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{0}{e^{-x\cdot \ln(1-t)}\cdot (-\ln(1-t))}=0.\end{align}$$
Are my calculations correct?

Comment: While it doesn't affect the final result, your application of L'Hopital the first time is missing a negative sign on the denominator. Also, your application of L'Hopital the second time is incorrect since the expression is not of indeterminate form (you can directly argue that the limit evaluates to zero).

Comment: I corrected the signs.

Answer (score 1):

For $t=0$ and $t=1$ the answer is zero, so we consider the case when $t\in (0,1)$. Your calculation is correct except for the last step.

$\frac{1}{e^{-xln(1-t)}}=(1-t)^x$. Now there is no need to use L'Hospital again. This is because $0<1-t<1$ so $(1-t)^x$ goes to zero when x goes to infinity.